# discord.js bot messages and responses from an array

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Basically I'm trying to get my discord.js v12.0.0 bot to respond to certain words and the words and responses are in arrays. I seem to be getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const message = new Discord.Message();

var messages = ['ayy','stop','ok','wait','help'];
var responses = ['Ayy','stop','ok','i am sorry','you getting nothing'];
var content = message.content.split(' ');

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.includes(responseObject[message.content])) {
        message.channel.send(responseObject[message.content]);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Well, `message.content` is undefined since you are creating an empty message object. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you need to place `var content = message.content.split(' ');` inside the `message` event

and get rid of `const message = new Discord.Message();`

Answer (score -1):

```js
var names = [
  "**Bill Gates**: ",
  "**Ken Kaneki**: ",
  "**Steve Jobs**: ",
  "**Joe Mama**: ",
  "**Lonely hobo on the streets**: "
]

var answers = [
  "Ok buddy, now get da hell 'outta here.",
  "Begone, thot",
  "What? U want money? Naa bro, u just gonna use it to buy weed",
  "No parents.",
  "Naa fam"
]
var randomAnswer = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)] + answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)]
console.log(randomAnswer);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes